# WSO2 - access token validation failed error message returned when making API calls

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have started facing an issue where I can no longer make API requests shortly after requesting a new access token from our WSO2 instance.

After getting the new new token and making a subsequent API request, I get the following error:

```
code: 900901
description: Access failure for API: xxxx, version: v1 with key: <access_token_here>. Make sure your have given the correct access token
message: Invalid Credentials
```

In our API Manager system logs (carbon application), I can see the following:

```
Invalid OAuth Token : Invalid input. Access token validation failed
```

I understand what the error is, I just don't understand why it happens right after I have just requested a new token and try to use it for API requests.

I was able to make API requests fine up until recently. The only thing I can think of is that maybe my access to the API's is being blocked for some reason.

I have been experimenting with dealing with token expiry cases when making an API request, handling the expiry (refreshing the token) and using the new access token retrieved to re-perform the original API request. I have had some situations with the code I have written to do this where it has misbehaved and ended up spamming the WSO2 gateway, so I'm wondering if this is down to some throttling threshold I have breached and so my API access has been restricted? The API's I am subscribed to are with Unlimited Usage, so I can't see it being this.

I can request new tokens and make subsequent API requests using other accounts, so this makes me think it has to be something specific to my own login. Is there anyway I can debug this further through viewing certain WSO2 logs?

FYI - We are using WSO2 API Manager version 1.9

Answer (score 3):

There can be only 2 causes for this error.

1. The token is invalid.
2. The token is expired or revoked.

To debug the issue, check the `validity_period` of token response. Also, you can check the token state in `IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN` table.

Comment: I found the token is still valid in database. But still `code` (900901) - Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have given the correct access token"

Comment: Did you check the expiry time? The token can be exxpired even if the database says it's ACTIVE.

Comment: I resolved it already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55137885/4408610)

Answer (score 0):

How did you request a new access token? Did you use the API Store console? In that case the previous token is revoked (invalidated) and new token is requested.

When using application specific tokens (client_credentials), seems only a single token instance is assigned to the specific application (ClientKey) and that is returned until expired or revoked. I assume it will be similar with user tokens (password or code profiles).

There we leverage the "Production" and "Sandbox" keys of the configured application. I'd suggest you keep the "Production" keys to be used by your real application and you can "play" on the API Store console with sandbox tokens.

Comment: Im just making regular HTTP requests using postman to our token endpoint (using password grant type with username and password supplied) and then when a token is requested and returned, I am making api requests against our api gateway endpoint using the access token in an Authorization header. I have been doing this fine for a while now, up until recently where I started getting this error.

Comment: @mindparse then as Bhathiya answered, the token may really be invalid, revoked or expired. Be sure you don't exceed the "expires_in" time returned along the token and check the IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN database table (assuming you're using a serious database, not the embedded default one)