# WSO2 AM access token expires after one access time

Tags: wso2, access-token, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I setup IS as Key Manager for API-M, then I use Postman to get the access token from IS with Client Credential Grant Type.

[image]

However, the above token can be only used for the 1st request only. I used it with the second request, I found following

[image]

It seem like the token expired after one access time.
Is there any document explains about this, and what should I change ?

Comment: Have you added authorisation of consumer-key:consumer-secret while generating access token ?
In WSO there is no such kind of setting which will revoke your access token after 1st request. Either you have to manually call `/revoke` api or it will get expired in Time mentioned by you.
Also double check value of `<AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>` element in the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml` is set to 3600.

Comment: What is the type of database you are running on?

Comment: @AshwinK, I already add the consumer key and secrete in when generating access token. <AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod> value is 3600 as well. I don't manually trigger /revoke api. :(

Comment: @Gayan, I use PostgreSQL database

Answer (score 1):

The issue come from the different time set up on the servers of API-M and IS.

- With the first time the request comes, I believe that API-M trust in the result `active=true` received from IS, and cache the `expire-in` time
- For the second request comes, API-M calculates expiration of token based on `expire-in` and the system time of server, and indicates that it expired

Answer (score 0):

You can check  IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN -> TOKEN_STATE column to get an idea about actual state of access token. You can check token state before and after first request. Meanwhile can you briefly explain APIM/IS versions and nature of deployment (fully distributed, single node ... etc) ?

Comment: Check the API-M, it logs: `[AM] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator} -  Invalid OAuth Token : Access Token 5027beb5-5ca2-31c3-ad7b-c25aa5fb7439 expired.                {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator}`
Check the IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN: it's `ACTIVE`

Comment: I setup them according to [This link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager)

Comment: I use AM 260 + IS KM 570